# Update and Convert Date Column with SqlDataSource Update Command

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, date, datetime

I have a DetailsView and `SqlDataSource` with Select/Update/Delete Command .

This is my code :

```
<asp:DetailsView ID="DetailsView1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" AutoGenerateRows="False" HeaderText="Rechnung Details" DataKeyNames="InvoiceID" CssClass="table table-striped table-bordered" EmptyDataText="Rechnung ist nicht vorhanden!">
    <Fields>
       ....
       <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True" />
    </Fields>
</asp:DetailsView>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:RechnungConnectionString %>" 
    SelectCommand="SELECT Invoice.[InvoiceID], Invoice.[InvoiceManual], Invoice.[CustomerID], Invoice.[Date], Invoice.[Amount], Invoice.[Total], Invoice.[Paid], Invoice.[Rest], Invoice.[PaymentType], Invoice.[Shipped], Customer.[CustomerID], Customer.[Name], Customer.[Tell], Customer.[Address], Customer.[Comment] FROM [Invoice] INNER JOIN [Customer] ON Invoice.[CustomerID] = Customer.[CustomerID] WHERE Invoice.[InvoiceID] = @InvoiceID AND [Invoice].IsDeleted != 1"
    UpdateCommand="UPDATE [Invoice] SET Invoice.[InvoiceManual]=@InvoiceManual, Invoice.[Date]=<%# CONVERT(Date,@Date,103) %>, Invoice.[Amount]=@Amount, Invoice.[Paid]=@Paid, Invoice.[PaymentType]=@PaymentType, Invoice.[Shipped]=@Shipped WHERE [InvoiceID]=@InvoiceID"
    DeleteCommand="UPDATE [Invoice] SET Invoice.[IsDeleted] = 1 WHERE [InvoiceID]=@InvoiceID">
     <SelectParameters>
      <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="InvoiceID" QueryStringField="ID" />
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

And this is my table wants to update from detailsview :

```
1001    14-1001 1000    2014-12-15  250.00  297.50  100.00  197.50  Bar 1   0   0
1002    14-1002 1001    2014-10-10  250.00  297.50  0.00    297.50  Bar 1   0   0
1006    14-1003 1001    2014-05-10  500.00  595.00  200.00  395.00  Bar 1   0   0
1007    13-1004 1001    2013-12-10  450.00  535.50  100.00  435.50  Überweisung 1   0   0
```

but the problem Date column in detailsview is `{dd.mm.yyyy}` ( German ) and Database's Date column is `{yyyy-mm-dd}` i need some converting or something else , i try `Invoice.[Date]=<%# CONVERT(Date,@Date,103) %>` in UpdateCommand but dont work .

Comment: Why don't you add a **parameter** for the date column to your `UPDATE` statement (like you have for all the other values) and just set that parameter in code?

Comment: becuase i want to write `{dd.mm.yyyy}` in Date textbox in edit mode but the Database only accept `{yyyy-mm-dd}` this syntax !

Comment: If you would use a `DateTime` parameter, then you can get around all those messy string-to-date-and-back conversions! A `DateTime` is a `DateTime` is a `DateTime`, it doesn't have any *format* with it....

Comment: @marc_s can u show me how can i do that ?!